# Get current timestamp in specific format with seconds to one decimal place

Tags: oracle, datetime

I'm trying to set a value in an Oracle database that resembles the following:

```
2016-06-21 03:07:25.0
```

It is a varchar of the current date with one digit after the decimal for seconds. I tried multiple ways to achieve this but to no avail:

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
--------
21-06-16
```

From this I tried:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.F';
ERROR:
ORA-01821: date format not recognized

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.s';
ERROR:
ORA-01821: date format not recognized
```

Then I tried:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YY
-------------------
2016-06-21 12:58:55
```

Since that worked up to the seconds I tried the decimal part:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.SSSS') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM
------------------------
2016-06-21 13:23:47.4747
```

So I can get 4 significant places. Now I try with just 1:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.S') from dual;
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.S') from dual
                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01821: date format not recognized
```

So how can I get the current timestamp in the abovementioned format with seconds set to one decimal place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SSSS` isn't fractional seconds. It's just repeating the `SS` value twice; in your example you get 13:23:47.4747 - the 4747 is just 47 displayed twice. Maybe you were thinking of `SSSSS`, but that is the number of seconds since midnight (i.e. 0-86399) so isn't useful here either. A single `S` isn't a [valid format model element](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212).

Dates don't have fractional second precision. A single `F` isn't a valid format model element either, but even `FF` isn't valid for a date.

You need to use [`systimestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions192.htm) to get the server time with fractional seconds, rather than [`sysdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions191.htm):

```
select to_char(systimestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MM
-----------------------------
2016-06-21 14:42:22.7
```

Storing a date/time as a string is generally a bad idea. I'd suggest you make the column `timestamp(1)` which will keep the one-decimal-place precision when you set it from `systimestamp`. You can see what it would get with `cast`:

```
select to_char(cast(systimestamp as timestamp(1)), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9') from dual;

TO_CHAR(CAST(SYSTIMESTAMPASTI
-----------------------------
2016-06-21 14:49:09.900000000
```

Converting a date/time to a string should really only be done for display, not for storage.